# Access to SQL Server BLOB Picture Format

Tags: sql-server, image, ms-access, reporting-services, blob

I have an Access 2016 form where data entry users copy and paste pictures into a Bound Object Frame that is linked to a SQL Server 2016 varbinary(max).  Pictures are copied from Snip and Sketch.  When using Access, all is wonderful.  Pictures can be seen, can be put in a report, and replaced, if needed.

The problem comes in when using SQL Server Reporting Services 2016.  I have tried to get these pictures out, but I don't know if they're jpg, dib, bmp, tiff, or any other format, so my question is:
What format are pictures sent to SQL Server from Access?

The copy/paste option is great for data entry, but the need to have a web based (SSRS) delivery to the customer (manufacturing floor) is paramount, so if there's a better way to store these pictures in a controlled format so I can retrieve them in SSRS, that is a solution as well.

Comment: I recall Access stores images OLE objects. The images are stored as bytes and SQL Server has no notion of what those bytes represent. It is up to the app code to interpret those values and render accordingly. I think your question is ultimately actually how to render an OLE image in SSRS.

Comment: have you tried setting the Image Source `=System.Convert.ToBase64String(Fields!myImageColumn.Value)` ?

Comment: If you use bound OLE object frames, pictures are stored as OLE objects, and depending on the type of frame you're using, might contain a variety of types, some with multiple files in a single BLOB. The only real way to work with these is from within Access, if you don't want to put in a ton of effort to reverse-engineer these OLE objects (Stephen Lebans OleToDisk reverse engineers a couple of them in VBA). I strongly recommend reworking your forms to use the raw picture data instead of using OLE objects.

Comment: @DanGuzman  You are correct, if you have a way to use the OLE objects in SSRS, that would be helpful.

Comment: @ErikA That is what I'm looking to do.  The data entry will be more difficult, however the real benefit will be to the users.  I can re-do the 50 or so items I already have in the database to make them into pictures that are usable by SSRS.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I'll look into this as well.  I'm not sure what this will do; if you have context for this (a URL), that will help.
Thank you all for your answers!